# Capturing cancel event from browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using the following code to create an document.createElement reference, but I am unable to handle if the user clicks cancel. any inputs on how to achieve it ? I am using Angular.

My Typescript code is given below

```
downloadFile(){
      url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;utf-8,test';
      let link = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.href = url;
                link.download = fileNameToBeDownloaded + '.xls';
                link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(`click`, {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));}
```

HTML code is given below

```
 <button type="button" (click)=downloadFile() [disabled]="selectedFileId=='' || selectedFileId==undefined || selectedFileId=='Select' " class="btn btn-primary btn-md btnStyle">Download as a file</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code

Comment: `<button type="button" (click)=downloadFile() [disabled]="selectedFileId=='' || selectedFileId==undefined || selectedFileId=='Select' " class="btn btn-primary btn-md btnStyle">Download as a file</button>` @GeorgeC.

Comment: how your html code related with the typescript code????

Comment: can you update your question. and please put any code on your question and not on the comments section

Comment: Where the **link.dispatchEvent** comes from, I am trying to understand your code

Comment: done that @GeorgeC.

Comment: Thanks, now are more clear, and I can help you